# I cannot link toolchain to different github organization

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery, ibm-cloud-tools

I have a github account: https://github.com/remkohdev 
and am a member of several github organizations

I have added all organizations to the Bluemix DevOps Third Party applications authorizations.

But I cannot change the default github organization to a different organization when I enable the Toolchain on Bluemix, so that I can create/edit the source code to the repo in a different than default Github organization?

[image]

Error:
The integration could not be set up. Check the settings and try again.
Reason: Unable to update the git integration. An error occurred while cloning the git repository. Error details: Unable to read the repository on: https://github.com/eventquarry/server.git. User is not authorized, or repository does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

When you authorized with GitHub you probably did not explicitly grant access to the eventquarry organization.

To fix this, first you need to revoke your token by logging into Github.com, then click settings > Authorized applications > Revoke "IBM Bluemix Toolchains". Now go back to Bluemix, and when you click on the GitHub tool you will see an “Authorize” button. Upon clicking, you will be taken to GitHub, and here you need to click "Grant Access" next to eventquarry (and all orgs you would like to grant access to) before clicking "Authorize application".

Now you should be able to fork/clone/link with the private repositories in the eventquarry organization.

Comment: I was also able to set it up very smoothly via the hub.jazz.net option instead of the Toolchain option actually. In the jazz.net option, I was able to use the options select dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The devops git folks responded with this:

Right now, we don't support the ability to create new organization repositories through the toolchain UI.  Any new repos are created under the personal account of the user.  It is possible to link to existing organization repos by typing in the repo URL in the field.  (Org repos won't show up in the dropdown, but the URL can be entered manually.)  Note that the user needs admin privileges on the repo they're linking to in order to have a fully functioning integration though.  It's possible to link to a repo without admin privileges, but we can't create a webhook on the repo, so there's no way for us to be notified of commit events.  Pipelines will only run manually if the user doesn't have admin privileges on the repo.

Let me know if this is helpful...

Comment: Yeah that didnt work, cause it doesn't pick up the 'other organization's Github url, tried it.

Comment: I d appreciate some help, this is a very basic scenario imo, as a developer working for a different github organization, or even multiple: my own, my work, my project... thats pretty default no? it prevents me from doing anything on Bluemix at the moment really.... also my github repo is private, which seems also pretty normal.